# Locating an Event Handler

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, event-handling, breakpoints

I have the source code for a very large MFC application with poor documentation.  I'm attempting to trace through the code as it executes in order to understand what it's doing.  Unfortunately, as soon as the user gains control over the application, I need to have a breakpoint set on an event handler in order to start following again in the debugger.  If I try to step through the code line by line, then the user will never gain control of the application, since it starts walking step by step through the idle routines instead.

What I need is to determine the name of the event handler associated with a button before I click it.  That way, I can set a break point on that event handler and walk through the associated code as soon as it's been pressed.

Due to the size of the application, manually setting break points at every event handler is not feasible.  If there were an easy way to set breakpoints on all lines that contained a certain pattern, then that would work too.  I could search (alt+e+f+i) for '::On' and set breakpoints on the thousands of resulting hits all at once.  I'd have to manually deselect all the breakpoints that got triggered inadvertently that way, but this would still work.  Is there a way to do this?

Additionally, I've tried searching through the resource viewer and finding something that looked like the button I want, but have been unable to find it.  Even if I did, I'm not sure how that would help.  Shouldn't there be a nice easy list somewhere that lists graphical elements alongside their associated events?

**What are my remaining options?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your app is a fairly standard MFC app almost all button clicks will be handled through the message map, and will look something like:

```
ON_BN_CLICKED( IDC_BUTTONID, OnMyButtonClicked )
```

which maps the BN_CLICKED notification for the button IDC_BUTTONID to the method OnMyButtonClicked.

Therefore the easiest way to find an event handler is to search the source code for the resource id of the button (which you should find in the dialog editor or the .rc file). Obviously, if you want to be a bit more specific you could do regex search, e.g.

```
ON_BN_CLICKED.*IDC_BUTTONID
```

It is possible that the item looks like a button but isn't actually a button, or it's been manually routed through OnCmdMsg in which case you might be better off looking for a symptom of the click (ie a bit of code you KNOW must be run) putting a break there and then following the call stack to see how the messages are being handled.

For extensive source code searching I'd recommend looking at a dedicated 3rd party search program like [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack) or [WinGrep](http://www.wingrep.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Okay, the first thing I would do is what you apparently have already tried:  Look for the resource ID of the relevant control in the resource viewer.  If you have the ID, you can then search for it in your class declaration where there will be MFC macros mapping the 'click' event to a callback for that control.  The callback, of course, is the event handler you're looking for.

So, if you can't find the button with your eyes, search for it.  There's a few reasonable possibilities:

1. It's in the resource file but you can't see it - maybe it's covered by other buttons;
2. It's dynamically named in the application;
3. It's dynamically created in the application.

Search your project for the text that appears on the button - match case and try including the quotes first, then without quotes if unsuccessful.  You might have to open and search the resource file manually (close the resource editor and load the RC file into Visual Studio as text, then search).

If it's in the resource file, you'll be able to match the control to an ID.  If you can't find it at all, check in the string table.  If it's in the string table, then trace back where that string resource is used.

In the case of dynamic naming and/or creation, you might have a bit more detective work to do.

The worst thing that could happen with this approach is that the text on your button appears all through the project, or that the button has an icon and no text.  If you are really struggling, you might get somewhere by using Spy++ to get information about the button.  You should be able to retrieve the numeric ID from it and then go hunting for it in `resource.h`.

Have fun!